# c function to erase all the binary tree elements

Tags: c, binary-tree

a C-lang function that erase all the elements of the tree, it doesn't crush when I call it but the result when I'm trying to display the tree or call any function giving it the (_root) as a parameter, it crushes

```
void free_tree(tree *_root) {//testing, not working
    tree p= *_root;
    if (p) {
        if (p->left) free_tree(&p->left);
        if (p->right) free_tree(&p->right);
        free(p);
    }
}
```

I verified any other thing outside the function that can cause the bug but seems everything works great, thanks anyone can answer

Comment: Why don't you work on _root but you declare another variable ?

Comment: Assuming that the type of e.g. `p->left` is `tree*` (I have to assume since you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), then what do you think `&p->left` will give you?

Comment: Move parts of the code to a separate file and provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example and post it here.

Comment: @Hearner I work with dev c++ program, it doesn't recognize the element with *_root

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude programmer dude tree is a type that already points to a node, so what's the meaning of assuming that p->left is of type tree*, even though, &p->left still gives a error on this case since it is not a pointer to a node bout a pointer  points to a pointer that points to a node.

Comment: Well how could we know? That's why http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, and also http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: here is a part of the code:
[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkEail-kUdTkl21C-yZ0-bpSPm5s)

Comment: Crash seems to be triggered because you are using freed memory. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `*_root` to NULL. Since the function calls itself recursively, only the first actual parameter will be the root node, so I would instead simply name the parameter *t*. Also, the left/right null checks are not needed. Try this:

```
void free_tree(tree *t) {
    tree p = *t;
    if (p != NULL) {
        free_tree(&p->left);
        free_tree(&p->right);
        free(p);
        *t = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AugustKarlstorm thanks, I thought the last instruction is done automatically but seems I have a misunderstanding of how free() works. thanks again :)